# Laravel 4 to 5 Models

Tags: laravel, model, upgrade, laravel-5

Hi can anyone clarify this for me. I have a rather large Laravel 4 app using a few models. I would like to upgrade to L5 and would simply like to use the same model calls in the controllers.
e.g.

```
 Course::
\Course:: //if controller in a deeper folder
```

The course model is in App/Models. I've tried a composer mapping App/Models but to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about anyone else. But in my installation of Laravel 5, my models are defined directly within the `app` folder. The `app` directory is psr-4 namespaced as `App`.

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

Models are then defined under the `App` namespace. e.g.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model {

}
```

So you can either:

**1:** Use the full path to the model whenever you use it:

```
\App\Course::all();
```

**2:** `use` your model before using it like you normally would:

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use App\Course;

class YourClass {

    public function yourFunction()
    {
        Course::all();
    }

}
```

**3:** Create a folder called `Models`, put your models in there and make sure that their namespace reflects the path (And then call the model like in options 1 and 2):

```
// app/Models/Course.php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model {

}
```

e.g.

```
\App\Models\Course::all();
```

or

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use App\Models\Course;

class YourClass {

    public function yourFunction()
    {
        Course::all();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just how namespaces work. If you specify a class PHP will always search for it *relative* to the current namespace. Unless you prepend a backslash and use the **full path** or add an import statement at the beginning of your files:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Course;

class ...
```

Or

```
\App\Models\Course::all();
```

---

I should add that many editors and IDEs are able to automatically resolve and import classes, so with the right tools it's not that cumbersome...